# Unattended-upgrades disagrees with update-notifier

Tags: apt, lts, unattended-upgrades, update-notifier

Ubuntu Server 18 LTS here, with `unattended-upgrades` installed, and security repo enabled. It is working, as confirmed by `tail /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log`.

Running `sudo unattended-upgrade -v` manually returns the same as the most recent log entry:

```
Initial blacklisted packages: 
Initial whitelisted packages: 
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=bionic, o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=bionic
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

Running `sudo apt-get upgrade -s | grep -i security` returns nothing.

But `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable` (which powers the message of the day) returns:

```
167 packages can be updated.
1 update is a security update.
```

What is broken?

**Update.** Today the `apt-check` count had increased to "4" pending security updates. Subsequently, running `unattended-upgrade -v` found and installed 3 packages. As expected, `apt-check` now returned "1" pending security update. **What is the missing package, and above all why is `unattended-upgrades` not installing it?**

**New update.** Resorted to [this](https://serverfault.com/a/282518) hacky solution of forking a security-only `security.sources.list` and then doing `sudo apt-get upgrade -o Dir::Etc::SourceList=/etc/apt/security.sources.list`. Result: a bunch of packages were upgraded and `apt-check` now, at last, shows "0" pending security upgrades. **Still no idea what the supposedly crucial package was, or how to avoid this situation in future.** Sigh.

**Yet another update. Still an issue in LTS 20:**

```
$ sudo apt update
// OK
$ /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
254 updates can be applied immediately.
38 of these updates are standard security updates.
$ sudo unattended-upgrade -vvv
// some stale kernels autoremoved
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
$ /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
254 updates can be applied immediately.
38 of these updates are standard security updates.
```

Naturally the previous hacky solution got overwritten at some point and I don't feel like putting it back. Result: more missing "security updates" than ever, on a standard LTS. All this is not very reassuring, frankly.

Comment: Maybe try `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check -p` to see what packages it lists, and check what those packages' statuses are.

Comment: It show the names but how to see which "1" of the 167 packages is the security update? `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --security-updates-unattended` returns nothing.